# Phone Gap: Button click is not working in Windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am developing a mobile application for windows, android and iOS in phone gap.I have button click event in a screen that is working in both Android and iOS  , but not working in Windows phone.

In that screen a **Drop down and a Button**. In Windows phone **when I click the button, drop down is opening** instead of action in button

**Index.html**

```
 <div id="selectSchoolDD" class="wrapper-dropdown-3">
             <label id="school_Selection" for="school_Selection">Select School</label>
             <ul class="dropdown" id="drop_down_school_list">
                 <!--<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Select School</a></li>-->
             </ul>
         </div>
           <button class="custom-button" type="submit" data-theme="a"  id="schoolSelectButton">GO</button>
```

**Java Script**

```
   $(document).on('click', '#schoolSelectButton', function() {
            alert("hello");
 });

 var dd = new DropDown( $('#selectSchoolDD') );
                                 $(document).click(function() {
                                   $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
                                 });
function DropDown(el) {

this.dd = el;
this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
this.val = '';
this.index = -1;
this.initEvents();
}


DropDown.prototype = {
initEvents : function() {

    var obj = this;
    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){

              $(this).toggleClass('active');
              return false;
              });

    obj.opts.on('click',function(){

        var opt = $(this);
                obj.index = opt.index();



                obj.val = selectedSchoolName[obj.index];
                $('#school_Selection').empty();
                $('#school_Selection').html(obj.val);



         });
},
getValue : function() {
                            return this.val;
},
getIndex : function() {
                            return this.index;
}}
```

**Screen Shoot**

[image]